# Avoid conversion in double in Spark SQL with schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple JSON as below, the value node sometimes will have STRING, and sometime will have DOUBLE. I want to treat the value as STRING as it comes. But when spark see that tag is double its converting to a different format with E

Input JSON

```
{"key" : "k1", "value": "86093351508521808.0"}
{"key" : "k2", "value": 86093351508521808.0}
```

Spark output CSV

```
k1,86093351508521808.0
k2,8.6093351508521808E16
```

Expected output

```
k1,86093351508521808.0
k2,86093351508521808.0
```

Please advise on how the desired output could be achieved. We never read the value in the tag, so we will never be aware of the precision and other details.

Below is the sample code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName(TestSpark.class.getName())
        .master("local[*]").getOrCreate();

    SparkContext context = sparkSession.sparkContext();
    context.setLogLevel("ERROR");
    SQLContext sqlCtx = sparkSession.sqlContext();
    System.out.println("Spark context established");

    List<StructField> kvFields = new ArrayList<>();
    kvFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("key", DataTypes.StringType, true));
    kvFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("value", DataTypes.StringType, true));
    StructType employeeSchema = DataTypes.createStructType(kvFields);

    Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.read()
        .option("inferSchema", false)
        .format("json")
        .schema(employeeSchema)
        .load("D:\\dev\\workspace\\java\\simple-kafka\\key_value.json");
    dataset.createOrReplaceTempView("sourceView");
    sqlCtx.sql("select * from sourceView  ")
        .write()
        .format("csv")
        .save("D:\\dev\\workspace\\java\\simple-kafka\\output\\" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    sparkSession.close();
```

}

Comment: Create case class and create  case class Person(key :String and value :String )
and map values.

Answer (score 1):

We can cast that column to DecimalType as follow:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType

scala> spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(Seq("""{"key" : "k1", "value": "86093351508521808.0"}""","""{"key" : "k2", "value": 86093351508521808.0}"""))).select(col("value").cast(DecimalType(28, 1))).show

+-------------------+
|              value|
+-------------------+
|86093351508521808.0|
|86093351508521808.0|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, we never read the value in the tag, so we will never be aware of the precision and other details.